# Centering Textview Below a image button that is under relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this problem of the textview is not centering below the image button. anyway to fix this issue? the coding and image is given below thx! 
[image]

```
   <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"> 

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnCat1"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="text" />

</RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnContact"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>






   <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"> 

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnRoute"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="text" />

</RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnChecList"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="text" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: would be great if reason of down voting is given :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this snippet :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="text" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="text" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can do, simply (!!!):

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/my_image_view"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/my_image_view"
```

just align it left and right together, the result is the TextView centered.

Comment: Using this approach, the width of the text will be limited to the width of the icon.  If the icon is narrow in comparison to the length of the text, the text will wrap several times.

Comment: Yes, tha workaround is to put the TextView inside of a ViewGroup (e.g. a FrameLayout) with width and height set to wrap_content, and set the attributes clipChildren and clipToPadding to false. This ViewGroup will be centered below the image and the TextView inside of it will be totally visible.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - tested in Android Studio's Design view and on a 5.0.x device.  I have a FrameLayout, set to wrap its content, with both clipping options set to false.  The TextView in the FrameLayout is still limited to the width of the icon it's centered below.

Comment: From my experience, in order to let clipchildren to work as you expect, you also have to set that property also to the grandparent of the textview... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26528854/1507512

Answer (score 4):

Just adding these values:

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

put the button and text view in the same vertical `LinearLayout` (and you can place the `LinearLayout` in a relative layout) and simply assign center gravity to the text view.

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` add this

Answer (score 0):

remove the line `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` from the textviews

or else try this

```
<LinearLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"> 

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="btnCat1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageButton>

        <TextView
            style="@style/MenuStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="@string/app_name" 
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

btw i tried doing it the opposite way. i changed from horizontal to vertical and it worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >


   <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"> 

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"   android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnCat1"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Cat 1" />


</RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnRoute"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Route" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>



   <LinearLayout  android:gravity="center" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"> 

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"   android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnContact"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="Contacts" />


</RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout  android:gravity="center"  android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 


  <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@null"
      android:onClick="btnChecList"
      android:src="@drawable/nopic" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    style="@style/MenuStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="CheckList" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>







</LinearLayout>
```