# Can't get clipChildren=false attribute to work

Tags: android, view

I have a yellow `RelativeLayout` containing a taller red `LinearLayout`.

In order to make the whole `LinearLayout` visible, I set `android:clipChildren="false"`, but this does not work as expected:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:clipChildren="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

- with `android:clipChildren="true"`:

[image]

with the red `LinearLayout` clipped as expected

- with `android:clipChildren="false"`:

[image]

where the `LinearLayout` height is clipped, and the width set in the layout is not respected.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

If I wrap the container in a `LinearLayout` with both dimensions matching its parent, I get the same result (I checked that the LinearLayout container's container fill the whole screen).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:clipChildren="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

If I put the `android:clipChildren="false"` attribute in the parent LinearLayout, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: the relative layout has android:layout_height="44dp". it is itself cliped by its parent

Comment: I set this layout directly with setContentView(R.layout.test);. There is no explicit parent. Doesn't the root Viewgroup fill the whole screen? And why is the width of the LinearLayout modified?

Comment: @njzk2: in order to do more test, I tried a different layout, and it still does not work (see my edit)

Comment: you have to put the android:clipChildren="false" in the parent LinearLayout

Comment: Still does not work. See my second edit.

Comment: any solution to this? I can't force this either

Comment: No, sorry. I guess I found another way to do it...

Comment: @jul and others here is the explanation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654808/294884

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Also set

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Beside:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

Comment: This is **wrong**.  The actual answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654808/294884

Answer (score 97):

`android:clipChildren="false"` allows each child to draw outside of its own bounds, within the parent. It doesn't allow children to draw outside of the parent itself. For that you would need to set `android:clipChildren="false"` on the grandparent (as well).

I think what you're seeing with the colors is just because colors have no inherent bounds. If there is nothing clipping them, colors go forever. My theory is that if you used, say, a stretched 1x1 px image instead of a color, things would be different.

Answer (score 0):

A trick which can solve your problem is to add some placeholder view

```
<View
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

in the relative layout and boom!

## Explanation

For me the boundary of relative layout seems to be different than the height.
The boundary seems to be where the content ends or where the parent ends. Adding some view to the bottom sets the boudary at the bottom so everything works fine.